# Bash: Is there an analogous command to `which` for shell functions?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm working with `Virtualenv`, which I found out (after a few google searches) that it creates a *shell function* called `deactivate` in my shell.

By looking through the package's files I found how it does that, but I was curious if there's a command similar to `which` which could have told me more about the shell function without me having to `grep` through files.

So the `which asdf` command tells me the path where the executable `asdf` is found. `which` however gives no output for shell functions. Is there a similar command that displays the function's code, or source file, or something of this sort?

Bonus: I'd highly appreciate some command to list the available shell functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` shows you all available shell functions.

I don't believe there's a way to figure out where a function was set historically, because I don't think the shell stores this information.

You might find `set -x` helpful to watch execution as it happens.

Comment: And aparently, the zsh `set` does things a little differently than tha bash `set`. For one, i could find my `deactivate` function with the bash `set`, but not with the zsh one.

Comment: In zsh, the command `functions` lists the functions.